# Right way to set up vc++ project with libraries in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a vc++ project that makes use of compiled library(freeglut in my case).Library consists of headers(.h) and 64/32bit libraries (.lib and .dll). I managed to get it working by dropping dll's in system32/sysWOW64 and setting absolute path to include and lib directories. But I'd like to know the proper way to set up linker and/or project dependencies in Visual Studio 17 so that all needed files can be inside project directory (relative path) and 64/32bit and Release/Debug builds worked. Thank you.

Comment: These support DLLs have very little to do with your project.  They just need to be found when you run your program, that's all.  Putting them in the OS directory is not very appropriate, imagine somebody else doing that on your user's machine and, invariably, copy a different version.  Proper way is a post-build event that uses xcopy /d to copy them to $(OutDir).

Answer (score 0):

The usual hierarchy for an installed library is the following:

- bin <- this is where you put the dll file, and you should add the path to the `PATH` environment variable
- include <- this is where you put the header files
- lib <- this is where you put the definition libraries (`.lib`).

Set then something like `%MY_LIBRARY_PATH%` to the folder where you have these three folders.

Then in your project, you can set the include path like `%MY_LIBRARY_PATH%/include` and the library to link with to `%MY_LIBRARY_PATH%/lib/mylibary.lib` in the properties of your project. It is possible to refine the latter to get the path in the list of the folders to explorer and then you only specify `mylibrary.lib` as the file to link to.

Comment: Thanks. That’s should do for my ptoject. How hard would it be to set up vs project template to accommodate a project like that? Microsoft docs weren’t really specific for vc++ project.

Comment: Usually, I set up this through CMake which generates my VS solution. I don't think there is a template for this, as it's on third party libraries, and not your current project. If you have several libraries, there is no way to set up a template.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a library you are going to want to use in many projects use the "Property Manager" window found under View->Other Windows rather than changing the properties for every project.

Open the debug node for each platform type and then right click on Microsoft.Cpp..User and select "Properties". You can then edit the user specified properties that are imported into every project for your user on that particular computer. You will want to add the paths under the "VC++ directories" node, in particular the "Include dictories" and "Library directories" lines.

Note that you should not simply copy files into the windows directory tree, choose some place else for files that are not managed by an installer (I use :\DevTools\ as a catch-all for this kind of thing). As another answer says if DLLs are involved you will also want to edit the PATH environment variable to include such a directory (this is in addition to the properties changes mentioned above).